# C program that reads a space/comma/tab delimited text file and copies its contents using a different delimiter to another text file

Tags: c, file, command-line, delimiter

I am fairly new to c and want to write a program that accepts command line arguments, which reads text from a delimited file, and writes the contents to a new file with a different delimiter.

The cmd input would be something like this:

prog.exe i:\test.txt i:\new.txt comma tab

to read from a comma delimited text file test.txt and copy its contents to text file new.txt using a tab delimiter.

I already made a portion of the program, but I am stuck at replacing the delimiter.

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
   FILE *fpr,*fpw;

   char dr[2]="",dw[2]="",buffer[300];

   fpr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   fpw = fopen(argv[2], "w");

   if (strcmp("comma", argv[3]) == 0) 
      strcpy(dr,",");
   else if (strcmp("space", argv[3]) == 0) 
      strcpy(dr, " ");
   else if (strcmp("tab", argv[3]) == 0)
      strcpy(dr, "\t");

   if (strcmp("comma", argv[4]) == 0)
      strcpy(dw, ",");
   else if (strcmp("space", argv[4]) == 0)
      strcpy(dw, " ");
   else if (strcmp("tab", argv[4]) == 0)
      strcpy(dw, "  ");

   while (!feof(fpr)) {
      fgets(buffer,300,fpr);//gets whole line to replace delimiter

      for (int i = 0; buffer[i]!='\n' && buffer[i] != '\0'; i++) {
         if (buffer[i]==dr){}
      }
   }



   return 0;
}
```

dr->delimiter in the file to be read ; dw->delimiter to be used when writing ;
fpr-> file pointer for file to be read ; fpw->file pointer for file to be written in

EDIT:Managed to get it to work.I wasn't aware that \t is treated as 1 character.

Comment: This is broken: `strcpy(dw, "    ")`. You'll generate undefined behavior copying 4 chars into an array that only holds 2 chars.

Comment: `while (!feof(fpr)) {
    fgets(buffer,300,fpr);` should be `while (fgets(buffer,300,fpr)) {`

Comment: Re first comment: the comment handler reduced 4 spaces to a single space. Plus a terminator is 5 array elements.

Comment: "I am stuck at replacing the delimiter" looks as simple as `if (buffer[i]==dr[0]) { buffer[i] = dw[0]; }`.

Comment: Re 4th comment.The tab character is \t which is two characters not one like space.Or is it treated like one character?This is the main issue.

Comment: The tab character is two characters in a text string definition but only one in the array. `\t` is two characters in the source code, but only one `9` (typically) in the array. `\t` is an "escape code"